# Codeigniter 3 force valid email format

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I am building a CRUD application in Codeigniter 3. I have an "Add customer" form with an *email address* field among others. I have managed to make this field required like so:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required');
```

I also need to force a valid e-mail format. What nut I add to the code above?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On CodeIgniter to validate email address on using form_validation library use

> `valid_email`

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email');
```

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#rule-reference

Answer (score 0):

```
//load Form Validation library
$this->load->library('form_validation');

 $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required');    
 if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
 {
        //Validation Error
 }
 else
 {
        $this->load->view('formsuccess');
 }
```